# What is a word for one who is depended on by another?

Tags: antonyms

What word can fill in the blanks in the following pair of analogous sentences?

```
If B is necessary to A, then A depends on B and A is dependent.
If B is necessary to A, then B __________ A and B is _________.
```

Is there a word, the opposite of "dependent", meaning "is depended on"?

---

Edit: 'requisite' fits the second blank:

```
If B is necessary to A, then B __________ A and B is requisite.
```

I don't know a form of 'requisite' that can fill the first.

Comment: You could say B 'serves' A, and B is 'of service'. Or B 'helps' A, and B is 'helpful'.  Or B 'provides for' A, and B is 'independent'.

Answer (score 1):

B 'is required by' A, and B is requisite.

Answer (score 1):

**provide**

If B is necessary to A, then B *provides for* A and B is *a provider* or *providing*.

> to make arrangements for supplying means of support, money, etc.
>   (usually followed by for):  He provided for his children in his will.
>
> to supply means of support (often followed by for):
>   http://www.dictionary.com/browse/provide

Other words:

- **support**  If B is necessary to A, then B *supports* A and B is *a supporter* or *supporting*.
- **supply**  If B is necessary to A, then B *supplies* A and B is *a supplier* or *supplying*.
- **care**  If B is necessary to A, then B *cares for* A and B is *a caregiver* or *caregiving*.

Comment: The system flags duplicate answers. Please do not post duplicate answers. As doing so indicates that the questions are duplicates, please flag for closure as duplicates instead [and, when you reach 3k rep, vote for closure].